# R xtable: LaTex Commands output to HTML

Tags: html, r, latex

I'm trying to use a LaTeX command to apply special formatting(shaded row) to one row of a table, and then to output it all directly to HTML.  I seem to be stuck in an "either/or" situation - either the LaTeX command is included and I get LaTeX output, or the command is omitted and I get HTML.  I want to press the "Knit" button and get a formatted report, with the shaded row included.

What's the flow from R code to LaTeX to HTML output, with one press of a button?

````
---
title: "Bug List"

output: 
  html_document

---

{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'} 
library(knitr,quietly = TRUE,verbose = FALSE)
library(xtable,quietly = TRUE,verbose = FALSE)
  data<-data.frame(matrix(as.character(rnorm(80,50,2)),ncol=8))
  names(data)<-c("BugActivity","Key","Summary","Priority","ExternalStatus","WaitingFor","InternalStatus","InternalBug")
  shadeCommand <- rep("\\rowcolor[red]{0.90}", 1)
  print(xtable(data), type="html",include.rownames= FALSE, floating=FALSE,
        add.to.row=list(pos=list(4),command=c("\\rowcolor[gray]{.8} ")))            
```
````

Environment: R Studio on Windows

Thanks very much!

Comment: Did you try to export "latex" format from `xtable` with the overall document in html format?

Comment: @daniel I did:  it gave me the columns separated by ampersands and the rows terminated with a \.  I assume this means it's raw LaTeX and needs to be processed before presenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I obviously have my biases...but `pixiedust`* allows you to create your tables in either latex or html using the same set of commands (although the latex output is a slightly more limited than the html).

````
---
title: "Bug List"
output:
  html_document: null
  pdf_document: null
header-includes:
- \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{arydshln}
- \usepackage{amssymb}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{multirow}
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(pixiedust)
set.seed(55)
data<-data.frame(matrix(as.character(rnorm(80,50,2)),ncol=8))
names(data)<-c("BugActivity","Key","Summary","Priority",
               "ExternalStatus","WaitingFor","InternalStatus","InternalBug")

dust(data) %>%
  sprinkle(rows = 5, 
           bg = "#D0D0D0") %>%
  medley_bw() %>%
  sprinkle_print_method("html")
```
````

If you want to change the output to latex, you just change the last line to `sprinkle_print_method("latex")`

`*` Use the dev version right now `devtools::install_github("nutterb/pixiedust")`.  That version should go up to CRAN sometime in late January.

Comment: This looks very good and I'm proceeding to modify my report. However, I'm having trouble modifying the table width.  Your documentation says that part="table" isn't supported.  And modifying the column widths is both cumbersome and conflicts with the overall table width, which can't be changed.  How do I get around this limitation?   Thx.

Comment: I'm not quite sure which part of the documentation you're reading, and it may need updating. If you want to apply an attribute to all columns in a table, you can use `sprinkle_table`, which will apply the setting to the column in all parts of the table.  If you want all columns to have the same width, you can accomplish that in one call to `sprinkle_table`.  Each separate width will require a new call (could be accomplished with a `for` loop).  Note also that in HTML, if you specify a width that is shorter than the natural length of the text, the cell will expand to the length of the text.